# awk: if a user defined function returns 1, start from the very beginning

Tags: awk

Let's say I have the following script:

```
function helper1() {
    if (NR==3 && !/PATTERN/) {
        return 1
    } else {
        if (NR>=13) {
            print $0
        }
        return 0
    }
}

BEGIN {
    if (helper1() == 1) {
            print $0
    }
}
```

Which means, I have a user-defined helper function, which checks a file if the 3rd line contains some PATTERN, and if that's true, then it prints out all the other lines starting from line 13.

But if it's not true (the helper function returns 1), then I'd like awk to print all the lines starting from line 1. Which is not happening :)

Would be grateful for any advice here,

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR < 3 {                # for first 2 lines
   s = s $0 ORS              # store all lines in a variable s
   next                      # skip to next record
}
NR == 3 {                    # for record number 3
   if (/PATTERN/)            # if PATTERN is found  
      p = 1                  # set flag p to 1
   else                      # else
      printf "%s", s         # print first 2 lines
}
(p && NR >= 13) || !p        # print if flag is not set or else if NR >= 13
' file
```

---

Using a function:

```
awk '
function helper1() {
   if (NR < 3) {
      s = s $0 ORS
      return 0
   }
   else if (NR == 3) {
      if (/PATTERN/)
         p = 1
      else
         printf "%s", s
   }
return (p && NR >= 13) || !p
}

helper1()
' file
```

Comment: Thanks! However, my point is also to make this little script sort of extensible with these little helper functions (like, there can be a certain variety of differently structured files, and I want the script to operate differently on all of them: first, we try `helper1()`, it failed, OK, next we try `helper2()`, it failed, ... , finally, if all other tests have failed, we just print out the file as it is). Is it possible somehow to do this with that helper functions approach? Or is a flawed strategy anyway?

Comment: It can be done in a function as well. Let me make modification in few minutes.